# Prove the Gram-Schmidt process for an inner product space.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, gram-schmidt

> Consider set of arbitrary non-zero vectors $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ in an inner product space $V$. Consider set $S = \{p_1,...,p_n\}$, where $p_1 = v_1$ and 
>   $$p_j = v_j - \biggr[\sum_{x=1}^{j-1}\frac{\langle v_j,p_x \rangle}{||p_x||^2}p_x\biggr]$$
>   where $j > 1$
>
> Show that $S$ is pairwise orthogonal.

My attempt:

By induction.

**Base case**: $j = 2$

We have $$ \langle p_1,p_2 \rangle = \big\langle p_1, v_2 - \frac{\langle v_2, p_1 \rangle}{||p_1||^2}p_1 \big\rangle = 0$$

**Induction step**:

Suppose for arbitrary $j < n$, it is true that for all $i < j$, $\langle p_i,p_j \rangle = 0$

Take $p_{j+1}$, and take arbitrary $k < j + 1$.

We have

$$\begin{align}\big \langle p_k, p_{j+1} \big \rangle & = \bigl \langle p_k,v_{j+1} - \biggr[\sum_{x=1}^{j}\frac{\langle v_{j+1},p_x \rangle}{||p_x||^2}p_x\biggr] \bigr \rangle \\
& = \bigl \langle p_k,v_{j+1} \bigl \rangle - \underbrace{\bigl \langle p_k, \sum_{x=1}^{j}\frac{\langle v_{j+1},p_x \rangle}{||p_x||^2}p_x\bigl \rangle}_{= \langle p_k,v_{j+1} \rangle} \\
& =0
\end{align}$$

Hence $S$ is pairwise orthogonal. $\blacksquare$

Is it correct?

Comment: Seems fine, I would be a bit more precise in where the induction hypothesis is used (and use $j=1$ as base case).